# Document removal workflow

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, document-library

I am trying to create a solution by creating a workflow that moves documents from one site collection to another upon request. We have users that do not have permission to delete documents and we don't want to give that permission, instead we want them to be able to move the document to a different library on a different site collection to be reviewed and decided by a lead whether or not the document should  be deleted. Also, we want to collect information about the need for the removal, such as: reason for removal and the source location of the document, as we have several libraries we want this solution be used in.

So the challenge is, first how to move the document to a different site collection and second, how to add the move reason and document origin with out changing the content types the different libraries use.

Answer (score 0):

If you are attempting to do this with SharePoint OOTB, you cannot move documents across site collections in a workflow.

A solution I could propose to this might be making the request process automated, but then manually moving the document across site collections, which you **can** do. When you select a document in the library, in the documents tab on the ribbon, you can select the Send To command. When using this, you would simply input the location of the document library you want to send it to.

Comment: Panic, thanks for the help. There is no limit to what tool I can use to achieve this. But I was inclined to use SPD2010 . I will also try your suggestion. Thank you!

Comment: I know that [Nintex Workflows](https://www.nintex.com/workflow-platform/workflow) have an action for copying documents across site collections, if you are interested in purchasing a 3rd party application.

Comment: I did Suggest that before and, I don't this they are willing to purchase a 3rd party tool. the send to command works great but, the limitation is that we cant capture move reason and 2 other metadata we need for the process. Also, once copied tot he detonation library, the users want the original document be deleted. hence, I think we are headed to VS to achieve all this.